# 'float' object is not iterable - it works for some columns but it doesn't for others

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 4 columns and 84 rows. All rows contain text. The issue is that, when I want to tokenize or remove punctuation it works with 2 of the 4 columns. The other 2 give error....cannot figure out why

[image]

Comment: check your data in column `Q18b`, there is probably a float value in it instead of string. Or use `"".join([char for char in str(text) if char in ...])`

Answer (score 0):

When you see `float` type things with non-float fields, it's generally because there are NaNs there. Try `df.fillna('')` first.